# Opencart DB error when importing products

Tags: mysql, sql, database, content-management-system, opencart

I'm importing products with module and got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error: Unknown column 'ref2' in 'field list'<br />Error No: 1054<br />INSERT INTO oc_suppler SET `suppler_id` = '1 ', `name` = '', `main` = '0', `sort_order` = '2', `rate` = '1', `ratep` = '1', `ratek` = '0', `cod` = '2', `item` = '1', `cat` = '5', `qu` = '', `price` = '4', `descrip` = '3', `pic_ext` = '', `manuf` = '', `warranty` = '', `ad` = '1', `status` = '5', `my_cat` = '0', `my_qu` = '99', `my_price` = '1', `my_descrip` = '', `my_manuf` = '0', `my_mark` = '', `weight` = '', `length` = '', `width` = '', `height` = '', `parent` = '0', `hide` = '1', `newphoto` = '1', `my_photo` = '', `cheap` = '0', `addopt` = '1', `addseo` = '0', `related` = '', `updte` = '1', `pmanuf` = '1', `upattr` = '0', `upopt` = '0', `upname` = '0', `myplus` = '', `cprice` = '0', `minus` = '1', `chcode` = '0', `importseo` = '1', `sorder` = '', `spec` = '', `upurl` = '0', `ref` = '', `ref1` = '', `ref2` = '', `ref3` = '',`addattr` = '0', `exsame` = '0', `sku2` = '', `parss` = '', `points` = '', `places` = '', `par in /home/sasha16/instrumentalka.store/www/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 41
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please add missing columns in table then try

Comment: You use some third party extension. Seems it not installed correctly. You can try reinstall extension. If this does not help contact extension developer for assistance, or try add missing column `ref2` to your DB table.